# The argument type 'editingtextcontroller' can't be assignedto the parametrer type 'String'

Tags: flutter

```
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('books')
                        .doc(widget.book.id)
                        .update(Book(
                          userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
                          title: _titleTextController,
                          author: _authorTextController,
                          photoUrl: _photoTextController,
                          startedReading: isReadingClick ? Timestamp.now():
                          widget.book.startedReading,
                          finishReading: Timestamp.now()
                          notes: _notesTextController,
```

this is part of code where are the error
[error image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDuzY.jpg
[statements] :https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntm1h.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the text of a [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) you need to call the getter `text`.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('books')
                        .doc(widget.book.id)
                        .update(Book(
                          userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
                          title: _titleTextController.text,
                          author: _authorTextController.text,
                          photoUrl: _photoTextController.text,
                          startedReading: isReadingClick ? Timestamp.now():
                          widget.book.startedReading,
                          finishReading: Timestamp.now()
                          notes: _notesTextController.text,
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow. Please make sure you describe your error well.

Solution, Please use .text property of the controller.

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('books')
                        .doc(widget.book.id)
                        .update(Book(
                          userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
                          title: _titleTextController.text,
                          author: _authorTextController.text,
                          photoUrl: _photoTextController.text,
                          startedReading: isReadingClick ? Timestamp.now():
                          widget.book.startedReading,
                          finishReading: Timestamp.now()
                          notes: _notesTextController.text,
```

You cannot assign a texteditingcontroller to those values as it is made for controlling your text. So you need to tap into the text it holds. So use its .text property. Since I don't know whether you are using null safety or not. I have assumed it as NO myself. Please feel free to ask if error occurs.